# Export automatically

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I work in a company, and i need to export one request SQL to CSV every month. I need to register this file in folder on the server of the company. I work with Oracle (sql developer).
Is this posible ?

Do you have any ideas or a way to resolve my problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Every month" leads to a *scheduled job* - use `DBMS_SCHEDULER` package to create it (or, if you're on older database versions, see `DBMS_JOB`).

"CSV file" leads to usage of a stored procedure and `UTL_FILE` package.

At the end, you'd have a job which periodically calls the stored procedure which - using `UTL_FILE` - creates a CSV file in a directory on the database server.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure your Oracle Server(NOT client) to SPOOL with tool UTL_FILE.

If you want to do it more faster, you can do it with command SPOOL into .SQL file.
There are some specifications like: you must to redirect the output to > /dev/null for example, but it is more eazy.